# Seaborn.histplot doesn't show full data with hue

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn, histplot

I'm trying to use 'seaborn.histplot()' to show from which of the categorical 'Destination' data has been 'Transported'.

[df_train description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FJTR.png)

`sns.histplot(df_train, x='Destination',hue='Transported')`

[this is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nw2C3.png)

as you can see, part of the the histogram is grey and it's doesn't clear how many was transported or not.

I thought it is something to do with Nan values, but after I removed them it stayed the same.
I'm expecting to see all the bars colored with orange and blue, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can try `sns.histplot(..., multiple='dodge')` or `multiple='stack'`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70649224/seaborn-how-to-use-multiple-parameter-in-seaborn-histplot. The grey color is the result of orange and blue overlapping.

Comment: Thank you! 'stack' did it for me, and the other thread explain it all.